# Jersey response.readEntity(...) sometimes returns null

Tags: jackson, jersey, jax-rs, json-deserialization

Consider this snippet from my REST client (Jersey 2.26). It's used to post objects and return the response object. If the REST server returns an error (status >= 400), then instead of returning an entity of type `T` I want to read an entity of type `ErrorMessage` and throw an exception containing the error message object.

```
protected <T> T post(final Class<T> type,
                     final Object entity,
                     final Map<String, Object> queryParams,
                     final String methodPath,
                     final Object... arguments) {
  return postResponse(
    getInvocationBuilderJson(methodPath,
                             queryParams,
                             arguments),
    entity
  ).readEntity(type);
}

protected Response postResponse(final Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder,
                                final Object entity) {
  return handleErrors(
    invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(entity,
                                         MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE))
  );
}

protected Response handleErrors(final Response response) {
  if (response.getStatus() >= 400) {
    throw new InvocationException(response.readEntity(ErrorMessage.class));
  }
  return response;
}
```

If no error occurs (status < 400), then my object of type `T` is returned as expected. However, when an error does occur, `response.readEntity(ErrorMessage.class)` returns `null`. But (and this is the strange part), this **does** get me data (at the `handleErrors` method):

```
byte[] data = readAllBytes((InputStream) response.getEntity());
```

I could use that and deserialize it manually.. but I would first like to know if there are any options to fix this without implementing workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching from the default MOXy JSON (de)serializer (we now are using a GSON provider) the problem was resolved.

We recently had a similar issue with JSON-B. There is turned out we had to add a getter and setter on our error object on order to (de)serialize the object.